# CKEditor destroy instances does not clean up classes and other attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, ckeditor

Im using CKEditor and tried to destroy the instances by these code

```
function DestroyAllCKEDITOR() {
    //Destroy all existing instances
    for (name in CKEDITOR.instances) {
        if (name != "template") {
            var editor = CKEDITOR.instances[name];
            if ((typeof (editor) != 'undefined') && (editor != null)) {
                editor.destroy(true);
            }
        }
    };
}
```

But after the instances got destroyed, i still have this line of code

```
<div class="item-container cke_editable_inline cke_contents_ltr" style="position: relative;" tabindex="0" spellcheck="false" role="textbox" aria-label="Rich Text Editor, editor1" title="Rich Text Editor, editor1" aria-describedby="cke_232">
```

I want to remove
class: cke_editable_inline cke_contents_ltr
aria-label, title, and describedby.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `editor = undefined` after `editor.destroy(true)`. I had the same problem and it worked for me!

Comment: it did not work for me